# Python DeepTranslator and GoogleTranslator not working with text?

Tags: python, google-translator-toolkit

I try to translate a text using the following code -

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = """ ดำเนินธุรกิจทางด้าน ผลิต ถุงพลาสติก ถุงบรรจุอาหาร พร้อมด้วย ถุงพิมพ์สอดสี ระบบกราเวียร์ อันทันสมัย นอกจากนี้ยัง ผลิตถุงขยะ, แผ่นพลาสติก Green House ที่มีลูกค้าทั้งในและต่างประเทศ ตลอดระยะเวลา 40 กว่าปีที่ผ่านมา บริษัทได้เติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องด้วยดีตลอดมา จนกระทั่งในปี 2532 บริษัทได้ขยายกิจการ โดยเพิ่มทุนจดทะเบียนเป็น 15 ล้านบาท มีการจัดตั้งเป็นรูปแบบโรงงานขึ้น ในพื้นที่ประมาณ 4 ไร่ บริเวณซอยประชาอุทิศ 23 เขตราษฎร์บูรณะ จังหวัดกรุงเทพมหานคร ด้วยการเจริญเติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องของบริษัท และเป็นการขยายกิจการ ทางบริษัทจึงย้ายโรงงานใหม่มาที่ ตำบลพันท้ายนรสิงห์ จังหวัดสมุทรสาคร ในปี 2552 มีการเพิ่มเครื่องจักรที่ทันสมัย และเพิ่มบุคลากรในด้านต่างๆ เพื่อให้เพียงพอต่อความต้องการของตลาดในปัจจุบัน – บริษัท สมบัติชายอุตสาหกรรมพลาสติก จำกัด เริ่มก่อตั้ง เมื่อปี 2510 ดำเนินธุรกิจทางด้าน ผลิต ถุงพลาสติก ถุงบรรจุอาหาร พร้อมด้วย ถุงพิมพ์สอดสี ระบบกราเวียร์ อันทันสมัย นอกจากนี้ยัง ผลิตถุงขยะ, แผ่นพลาสติก Green House ที่มีลูกค้าทั้งในและต่างประเทศ ตลอดระยะเวลา 40 กว่าปีที่ผ่านมา บริษัทได้เติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องด้วยดีตลอดมา จนกระทั่งในปี 2532 บริษัทได้ขยายกิจการ โดยเพิ่มทุนจดทะเบียนเป็น 15 ล้านบาท มีการจัดตั้งเป็นรูปแบบโรงงานขึ้น ในพื้นที่ประมาณ 4 ไร่ บริเวณซอยประชาอุทิศ 23 เขตราษฎร์บูรณะ จังหวัดกรุงเทพมหานคร ด้วยการเจริญเติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องของบริษัท และเป็นการขยายกิจการ ทางบริษัทจึงย้ายโรงงานใหม่มาที่ ตำบลพันท้ายนรสิงห์ จังหวัดสมุทรสาคร ในปี 2552 มีการเพิ่มเครื่องจักรที่ทันสมัย และเพิ่มบุคลากรในด้านต่างๆ เพื่อให้เพียงพอต่อความต้องการของตลาดในปัจจุบัน
ปัจจุบัน – บริษัท สมบัติชพลาสติก green house ที่มีลูกค้าทั้งในและต่างประเทศ ตลอดระยะเวลา 40 กว่าปีที่ผ่านมา บริษัทได้เติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องด้วยดีตลอดมา จนกระทั่งในปี 2532 บริษัทได้ขยายกิจการ โดยเพิ่มทุนจดทะเบียนเป็น 15 ล้านบาท มีการจัดตั้งเป็นรูปแบบโรงงานขึ้น ในพื้นที่ประมาณ 4 ไร่ บริเวณซอยประชาอุทิศ 23 เขตราษฎร์บูรณะ จังหวัดกรุงเทพมหานคร ด้วยการเจริญเติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องของบริษัท และเป็นการขยายกิจการ ทางบริษัทจึงย้ายโรงงานใหม่มาที่ ตำบลพันท้ายนรสิงห์ จังหวัดสมุทรสาคร ในปี 2552 มีการเพิ่มเครื่องจักรที่ทันสมัย และเพิ่มบุคลากรในด้านต่างๆ เพื่อให้เพียงพอต่อความต้องการของตลาดในปัจจุบัน
"""

from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
translated = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(text)
```

But when i running this code i get this error:

```
(test) C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\DeepTranslator>python exmplDeepTranslator.py
' ดำเนินธุรกิจทางด้าน ผลิต ถุงพลาสติก ถุงบรรจุอาหาร พร้อมด้วย ถุงพิมพ์สอดสี ระบบกราเวียร์ อันทันสมัย นอกจากนี้ยัง ผลิตถุงขยะ, แผ่นพลาสติก Green House ที่มีลูกค้าทั้งในและต่างประเทศ ตลอดระยะเวลา 40
ายกิจการ โดยเพิ่มทุนจดทะเบียนเป็น 15 ล้านบาท มีการจัดตั้งเป็นรูปแบบโรงงานขึ้น ในพื้นที่ประมาณ 4 ไร่ บริเวณซอยประชาอุทิศ 23 เขตราษฎร์บูรณะ จังหวัดกรุงเทพมหานคร ด้วยการเจริญเติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องของบริ
สาคร ในปี 2552 มีการเพิ่มเครื่องจักรที่ทันสมัย และเพิ่มบุคลากรในด้านต่างๆ เพื่อให้เพียงพอต่อความต้องการของตลาดในปัจจุบัน – บริษัท สมบัติชายอุตสาหกรรมพลาสติก จำกัด เริ่มก่อตั้ง เมื่อปี 2510 ดำเนินธุรกิจทาง
ัย นอกจากนี้ยัง ผลิตถุงขยะ, แผ่นพลาสติก Green House ที่มีลูกค้าทั้งในและต่างประเทศ ตลอดระยะเวลา 40 กว่าปีที่ผ่านมา บริษัทได้เติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องด้วยดีตลอดมา จนกระทั่งในปี 2532 บริษัทได้ขยายกิจการ โด
่ บริเวณซอยประชาอุทิศ 23 เขตราษฎร์บูรณะ จังหวัดกรุงเทพมหานคร ด้วยการเจริญเติบโตอย่างต่อเนื่องของบริษัท และเป็นการขยายกิจการ ทางบริษัทจึงย้ายโรงงานใหม่มาที่ ตำบลพันท้ายนรสิงห์ จังหวัดสมุทรสาคร ใน
เป็นการขยายกิจการ ทางบริษัทจึงย้ายโรงงานใหม่มาที่ ตำบลพันท้ายนรสิงห์ จังหวัดสมุทรสาคร ในปี 2552 มีการเพิ่มเครื่องจักรที่ทันสมัย และเพิ่มบุคลากรในด้านต่างๆ เพื่อใองด้วยดีตลอดมา จนกระทั่งในปี 2532 บริษัทไห้เพียงพอต่อความต้องการของตลาดในปัจจุบัน\n'
2033
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Python-Diverses\DeepTranslator\exmplDeepTranslator.py", line 16, in <module>
    translated = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(text)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\test\lib\site-packages\deep_translator\google.py", line 72, in translate
    raise RequestError()
deep_translator.exceptions.RequestError: Request exception can happen due to an api connection error. Please check your connection and try again
```

But this has nothing to do with my connection.
When i use another text or simply only provide one of this 2 lines in the text-variable the translation is working fine.
Why is this error happening with the full text with both lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a result of too many requests you made to Google servers. This is a "known limitation" and already documented in the projects GitHub as an issue:

[From the GitHub issue](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator/issues/182):

> ... not really related to deep-translator. The google server (or
> any other translation server actually) won't let you do many requests,
> as you might have guessed.
>
> In the past, I implemented some workarounds for it (e.g. the wait for
> 2, 3 seconds between requests), but still It won't solve the issue
> completely. One of the solutions that might work for you is to use a
> proxy, you can take a look in the documentation. There are some
> example on using proxies. Proxies are nice because the server would
> have no idea that you are making the requests all the time. Notice
> that using proxies is definitely slower as well, so you need to check
> if it is something for you.

Comment: Thx - but this is not the case. When I use another text or delete one line from the actual input then it works fine. There must be another reason